# Classification with large volume of missing data

Tags: classification, svm, missing-data

When building a model to classify a student is going to be admitted to a special program or not, the main features include,

```
gender | Ethnicity | State | Zip code | Test score | Education | Job title | Current gpa | Admission
```

As the data is collected online, many features are missing a lot of data. Feature 'Test score' should be important to the Admission decision, but it misses about 80%. Seems imputation is not practical.

Should keep it as a feature and use EM or Bayesian network, SVM those algorithms which are not sensitive to missing data, Or directly remove this feature when build model? Any suggestions?

Comment: You could try hunting for more data through linkedin or connect with an admission service with posting an official letter for your research and that you will not share any data. I also think You can eliminate zip code or state as both indicate pretty much the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. And yes, I have used only zip code and one-hot coded it. As for collecting more data, it is a good approach but not applicable for this particular issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **drop the feature**. The test scores can not be averaged out with just 20% of the scores present. Random values with a distribution can't be added either because they are test scores.

You could try building a model with the rows which consists of those values and see if it's effective or not.

Comment: Thanks. I'll explore both, filling missing values then build model, and another way is to remove this feature and build the model.